# combinatorics implementation in real life problems

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

How many ways there are to organize $7$ men in a row, if two insist on not standing next to each other? How do I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a total of $7!$ ways to organize the $7$ men in a row with no restrictions. Now we must count all the ways in which $2$ specific men stand next to each other, say person $x$ and person $y$. Treat these $2$ men as a single person. We can place these $2$ men in $2\cdot{6\choose 1}$ ways. We multiply by $2$ because we can have their order switched ($xy$ or $yx$). Now we will fill in the remaining $5$ places with the remaining $5$ men in $5!$ ways. Thus we can organize $7$ men in a row where $2$ men refuse to stand next to each other in $7!-2\cdot{6\choose 1}\cdot5!$ ways.

Comment: Im not sure I got you correctly but my line of reasoning goes like this: 7! is number of options to organize the 7 men. 6! is the options we have if we wish to organize 6 men in a row, if we treat 2 as one. taking into account internal order between the two we must double that by 2! Finally we must disgard all these options which would yield 7! - 6!*2! .

Comment: We have $7!$ ways to order the men with no restrictions. If we treat $2$ men as a single person we have to count all the ways we can place these $2$ men. There are ${6\choose 1}$ positions for them, but we have to take into consideration each mans position, so $2\cdot {6\choose 1}$ ways to order these two men. Then we fill in the remaining $5$ men with no restrictions for $5!$. Now we apply the Subtraction Principle and get the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Answer = (All number of ways) $-$ (The ways where the two are next to each other).

Comment: This is just what I was thinking. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

There five positions next to each other: $\;1-2,2-3,3-4,4-5,5-6\;$ (times two, as two people can interchange places with each other) , and for each of these there are $\;4!\;$ permutations for the other four men. You want *all the possible* arrangements except the ones described above...

Comment: Don't forget the $2!$ permutations of the 2 men standing next to each other.

Comment: Indeed so, @Geoffrey. Thanks.

Comment: Well put: helps explain the logic! +1